# closed unit ball with radius 1

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Is this subset compact in $l_1$ of all absolutely convergent real sequences, with the metric:$d_1(\{a_n\},\{b_n\})=\sum_{1}^{\infty}|a_n-b_n|$ closed unit ball centered at $0$ with radius $1?$  I guess not as it is not sequentially compact but I need one counter example.plz help

Comment: Counter example of what?

Comment: that it has a limit point outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $e^{(n)}\in\ell_1$ given by $e^{(n)}_k:=\begin{cases}1&\mbox{ if }n=k;\\\
0&\mbox{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$ Then $d\left(e^{(m)},e^{(n)}\right)=2$ if $m\neq n$ (because in the series giving the $\ell^1$ norm of $e^{(m)},e^{(n)}$,the terms with index $m$ and $n$ are equal to one while all the others are zero), which proves that the unit ball is not sequentially compact for $d$. A set which is not sequentially compact in a metric space cannot be compact.

In fact, the metric $d$ comes from a norm, namely $\left\lVert \left\{x_n\right\}\right\rVert=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left|x_n\right|$, and the unit ball of an infinite dimensional normed space is never compact for the topology of the norm.

Comment: +1    @Davide,,,,,But im not getting  how  $d(e^{(m)} ,e^{(n)) } = 2$   ..i thinks  It must  be $d(e^{(m) },e^{(n)}) = 1$.. can u elaborate that

Comment: @stupid I have included details in edit.

Comment: ,,@ Davide   im not getting still confused  according to ur edits ..im thinking like that   $ d(e^{(m},e^{(n)})  = d(1,1)  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |e^{m} -e^{n}|  =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |1-1| =  0  $

Comment: What does zhe equalityy $d(e^{(m},e^{(n)})  = d(1,1)$ mean? Maybe the $m$ and $n$ canconfuse you. As an advice, you could try to compute $d\left(e^{(1)},e^{(2)}\right)$ to see what happens.

Comment: here    $ e^1= 1$  and $ e^2 =1$...as  im not  getting  still  how  $d(e^1 - e^2)  = 2$

Comment: $e^1$ is a sequence.