# How $d\left(e^{(m)},e^{(n)}\right)=2$ ??

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Is this subset compact in $l_1$ of all absolutely convergent real sequences, with the metric:$d_1(\{a_n\},\{b_n\})=\sum_{1}^{\infty}|a_n-b_n|$ closed unit ball centered at $0$ with radius $1?$

I have  found this  question on here [closed unit ball with radius 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137353/closed-unit-ball-with-radius-1)

My confusion is[image]

My attempt :  take $e^{(m)} = (0,0,0,.....,1,0,......) $ and $e^{(n)} = (0,1,0,0..............,)$ now  $d\left(e^{(m)},e^{(n)}\right)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |e^{(m)} - e^{(n)}| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |1-1|=0$ 
Im getting  $0$  , How  $d\left(e^{(m)},e^{(n)}\right)=2 ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metric is defined by:

$d_1((a_n),(b_n))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n-b_n|$

Now we want to evaluate $d_1((e_k^{(n)}), (e_k^{(m)}))$ for $n\neq m$.

Example:

$n=1$ and $m=2$ then $(e^{(n)})=(1,0,0,\dotso )$ and $(e^{(m)})=(0,1,0,\dotso )$

So $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |e_k^{(n)}-e_k^{(m)}|=|1-0|+|0-1|+|0-0|+|0-0|+\dotso =2$

[Disclaimer: The notation above is just for the intuition and mathematically not sound.]

The general prove is basically the same.
If you understand the given example, you understand why the result has to be $2$.

Comment: thanks u  @ Cornman  really i missed this logics

Comment: @jasmine You are welcome. If you do not understand something it is often good to go by it step by step and check the definitions. Then make an example and work through that. This helps understanding what happens. Especially when there is something calculated. Here you had to understand how the metric works and that you are calculating with 'sequences'.

Answer (score 3):

The distance is not $\sum_n |e^{m}-e^{n}|$. It is $\sum_i |e^{m}_i-e^{n}_i|$ where $x_i$ denoted the $i-$th coordinate of $x \in \ell^{1}$. Note that two of the terms in this sum are $1$ and the rest are $0$.